# Sorting Through An Arraylist of Objects (Songs)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, filtering

So basically, this is a project where we are given a text file that contains a long list of songs. Using this file, we are supposed to make Song objects and be able to sort by and filter by artist, rank, year, and title. I have most of it working so far. The only thing I need help on is the sorting. The filtering methods seem to be working, but sorting does not (the filtering and sorting methods are in the SongCollection class). We are supposed to use insertion sort in one of the sorting methods, but it does not seem to be working.

[Input Text File](http://staff.rentonschools.us/hhs/ap-comp-science/ap-cs-projects/download/agazillionsongs.txt?id=312179)

Client Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GazillionSongs {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            //Prompt user to enter a file
            System.out.println("This will filter and sort songs.");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            //Stores file in arraylist
            Scanner f = new Scanner(new File("agazillionsongs.txt"));
            //makes array of songs
            ArrayList<Song> list = new ArrayList<Song>();
            //songcollection object
            SongCollection songs = new SongCollection(list);
            //stores songs in arraylist
            while (f.hasNextLine()) {
                Song song = new Song();
                song.parse(f.nextLine());
                list.add(song); 
            }
            //Filters
            System.out.println("Choose a filter. Year, rank, artist, or title?");
            String userInput = input.nextLine();
            //filters By year
            if (userInput.equals("year")){
                System.out.println("Enter a year or range:");
                String year = input.nextLine();
                songs.filterYear(Range.parse(year));
                songs.print();
                //filters by rank   
            } else if(userInput.equals("rank")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a rank or range:");
                String rank = input.nextLine();
                songs.filterRank(Range.parse(rank));
                songs.print();
                //filters by artist 
            } else if(userInput.equals("artist")) {
                System.out.println("Enter an artist");
                String artist = input.nextLine();
                songs.filterArtist(artist);
                songs.print();
                //filters by title  
            } else if(userInput.equals("title")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a title");
                String title = input.nextLine();
                songs.filterTitle(title);
                songs.print();
            } else if(userInput.equals("year and rank")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a year and rank");
                String year = input.next();
                String and = input.next();
                String rank = input.next();
                songs.filterYear(Range.parse(year));
                songs.filterRank(Range.parse(rank));
                songs.print();
            } else if(userInput.equals("artist and title")) {
                System.out.println("Enter artist and title");
                String artist = input.next();
                String and = input.next();
                String title = input.next();
                songs.filterArtist(artist);
                songs.filterTitle(title);
                songs.print();
            } else if(userInput.equals("year and title")) {
                System.out.println("Enter year and title");
                String year = input.next();
                String and = input.next();
                String title = input.next();
                songs.filterYear(Range.parse(year));
                songs.filterTitle(title);
                songs.print();
            } else if(userInput.equals("year and artist")) {
                System.out.println("Enter year and artist");
                String year = input.next();
                String and = input.next();
                String artist = input.next();
                songs.filterYear(Range.parse(year));
                songs.filterArtist(artist);
                songs.print();
            }
            //sorting
            System.out.println("Sort by what?");
            String sortInput = input.next();
            if(sortInput.equals("year")) {
                songs.sortY();
                songs.print();
            } else if (sortInput.equals("rank")) {
                songs.sortR();
                songs.print();
            } else if (sortInput.equals("artist")) {
                songs.sortA();
                songs.print();
            } else if (sortInput.equals("title")) {
                songs.sortT();
                songs.print();
            }
            //file not found
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
            System.out.println("File not found"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Song Class:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Song {
    //fields
    public int year;
    public int rank;
    public String artist;
    public String title;
    //constructor
    public Song(int y, int r, String a, String t) {
        year = y;
        rank = r;
        artist = a;
        title = t;
    }
    public Song() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    //parsing
    public Song parse(String s){
        //tokenizer
        StringTokenizer parse = new StringTokenizer(s, "\t");
        //year
        String yr = parse.nextToken();
        year = Integer.parseInt(yr);
        //rank
        String rk = parse.nextToken();
        rank = Integer.parseInt(rk);
        //artist
        artist = parse.nextToken();
        //title
        title = parse.nextToken();
        //song object
        Song song = new Song(year, rank, artist, title);
        return song;
    }
    //getters
    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }
    public int getRank(){
        return rank;
    }
    public String getArtist(){
        return artist;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    //tostring method
    public String toString(){
        return String.format(year + " " + rank + " " + artist + " - " + title + "\n");
    }
}
```

SongCollection Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SongCollection {
    //arraylist
    public ArrayList<Song> list;
    //constructor
    public SongCollection(ArrayList<Song> songs) {
        list = songs;
    }
    //filters by year
    public void filterYear(Range r) {
        for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!r.contains(list.get(i).getYear())) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    //filters by rank
    public void filterRank(Range r) {
        for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!r.contains(list.get(i).getRank())) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    //filters by artist
    public void filterArtist(String s) {
        for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!list.get(i).getArtist().contains(s)) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    //filters by title
    public void filterTitle(String s) {
        for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!list.get(i).getTitle().contains(s)) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
    //sorts by year
    public void sortYear(Song[] song){
        int in, out;

        for (out = 1; out < song.length; out++) {
            Song temp = song[out];
            in = out;

            while (in > 0 && song[in - 1].getYear() > 0) {
                song[in] = song[in - 1];
                --in;
            }
            song[in] = temp;
        }
    }
    //sorts by rank
    public void sortRank(Song[] song) {
        //insertion sort
        int in, out;

        for (out = 1; out < song.length; out++) {
            Song temp = song[out];
            in = out;

            while (in > 0 && song[in - 1].getRank() > 0) {
                song[in] = song[in - 1];
                --in;
            }
            song[in] = temp;
        }
    }
    //sorts by artist
    public void sortArtist(Song[] song) {
        //insertion sort
        int in, out;

        for (out = 1; out < song.length; out++) {
            Song temp = song[out];
            in = out;

            while (in > 0 && song[in - 1].getArtist().compareTo(temp.getArtist()) > 0) {
                song[in] = song[in - 1];
                --in;
            }
            song[in] = temp;
        }
    }
    //sort by title
    public void sortTitle(Song[] song) {
        //insertion sort
        int in, out;

        for (out = 1; out < song.length; out++) {
            Song temp = song[out];
            in = out;

            while (in > 0 && song[in - 1].getTitle().compareTo(temp.getTitle()) > 0) {
                song[in] = song[in - 1];
                --in;
            }
            song[in] = temp;
        }
    }
    // prints the songs
    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Song song = list.get(i);
            System.out.print(song.toString());
        }
    }
    public void sortY() {
        Song[] arr = list.toArray(new Song[list.size()]);
        sortYear(arr);
    }
    public void sortR() {
        Song[] arr = list.toArray(new Song[list.size()]);
        sortRank(arr);
    }
    public void sortA() {
        Song[] arr = list.toArray(new Song[list.size()]);
        sortArtist(arr);
    }
    public void sortT() {
        Song[] arr = list.toArray(new Song[list.size()]);
        sortTitle(arr);
    }
}
```

Range Class:

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Range {
    public static int min;
    public static int max;
    public static String str;

    public Range(String s){
        str = s;
    }
    public static Range parse(String s){
        //range
        if (s.contains("-")){
            StringTokenizer parse = new StringTokenizer(s, "-");
            String strMin = parse.nextToken();
            min = Integer.parseInt(strMin);
            String strMax = parse.nextToken();
            max = Integer.parseInt(strMax);

        }else{
            min = Integer.parseInt(s);
            max = min;
        }
        Range rangeObj = new Range(str);
        return rangeObj;
    }
    public boolean contains(int n){
        if (min <= n && n <= max){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public int getMin(){
        return min;
    }
    public int getMax(){
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a ton of code so I scanned but I see you starting loops with 1 not zero; is that intentional?

Comment: I'm assuming you can't use `Collections.sort`...

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I know it's a lot of code. I have the Song class and Range class working completely, so the only classes you need to look at are the Main class and SongCollection class. I tried changing the loops to start at 0 but sorting still does not work.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I guess we could use Collections.sort. However, one of the sorts has to include insertion sort, it doesn't matter what the other sorts use.

Comment: I guess the main thing I need help on is getting insertion sort working, because I can just use the same code for the other sort methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sort method should look something like this (just an example for sortYear(), the others should follow the same pattern. However, I guess it would make sense to reuse the sorting algorithm for the different sorting criterias....

```
public void sortYear(Song[] song){
        int in, out;

        for (out = 1; out < song.length; out++) {
            Song temp = song[out];
            in = out;

            while (in > 0 && song[in - 1].getYear() > temp.getYear() ) {
                song[in] = song[in - 1];
                --in;
            }
            song[in] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According my opinion you should not mutate you collection. It should contain all the elements. But you should be able to filter or order it as you need.
What I propose is to use google collections guava library https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Your class song can be more

```
public final class Song {
  public final String title;
  public final String artist;
  public final int year;
  public final int rank;

  public Song(final String title, final String artist, final int year, final int rank) {
    this.year = year;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.title = title;
  }

  // With Integer you have the function CompareTo so, you can use Integer instead of int
  public final Integer getYear() {
    return year;
  }

  public final Integer getRank() {
    return rank;
  }

  public final String getArtist() {
    return artist;
  }

  public final String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public final String toString() {
    return String.format(year + " " + rank + " " + artist + " - " + title + "\n");
  }
}
```

your sorting function can looks like this: The parsing can be moved to a dedecated class to separate concerns.

```
public List<Song> sortByYear() {
    Collections.sort(songs, new Comparator<Song>() {
        public int compare(final Song first, final Song second) {
            return first.getYear().compareTo(second.getYear());
        }
    });
    return songs;
}
```

And the to filter you can also use guava like this:

```
public Collection<Song> filterYear(final Range range) {
    return Collections2.filter(songs, new Predicate<Song>() {
        public boolean apply(final Song song) {
            return range.contains(song.getYear());
        }
    });
}
```

here an example of the class SongCollection:

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;

import static com.google.common.collect.Collections2.filter;
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;
import static java.util.Collections.sort;
import static java.util.Collections.unmodifiableCollection;

public class SongCollection {
  public final ArrayList<Song> songs;

  public SongCollection(final ArrayList<Song> songs) {
      this.songs = newArrayList(songs);
  }

  public Collection<Song> filterYear(final Range range) {
      return unmodifiableCollection(filter(songs, new Predicate<Song>() {
        public boolean apply(final Song song) {
            return range.contains(song.getYear());
        }
      }));
  }

  public Collection<Song> filterRank(final Range range) {
    return unmodifiableCollection(filter(songs, new Predicate<Song>() {
        public boolean apply(final Song song) {
            return range.contains(song.getRank());
        }
    }));
  }

  public Collection<Song> filterArtist(final String value) {
    return unmodifiableCollection(filter(songs, new Predicate<Song>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(Song song) {
            return song.getArtist().contains(value);
        }
    }));
   }

   public Collection<Song> filterTitle(final String title) {
    return unmodifiableCollection(filter(songs, new Predicate<Song>() {
        public boolean apply(Song song) {
            return song.getTitle().equals(title);
        }
    }));
  }

  public Collection<Song> sortByYear() {
    sort(songs, new Comparator<Song>() {
        public int compare(final Song first, final Song second) {
            return first.getYear().compareTo(second.getYear());
        }
    });
    return unmodifiableCollection(songs);
  }

  public void sortByRank() {
   ...
  }

  public void sortArtist() {
   ...
  }

  public void sortByTitle() {
    ...
  }

  // prints the songs
  public void print() {
    for (final Song song : songs) {
        System.out.print(song.toString());
    }
  }
}
```